# COPY two folders in docker (failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref)

Tags: docker

How can I copy two folders in docker? (Copying the parent folder and using dockerignore probably not an option).

I tried a simple dockerfile with two copy commands:

```
COPY ./node_modules/@prisma/client/inserter ./node_modules/@prisma/client/inserter
COPY ./node_modules/@prisma/client/mastip ./node_modules/@prisma/client/mastip
#COPY ./node_modules/@prisma/client ./node_modules/@prisma/client
```

however I got this error:

> ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to
> calculate checksum of ref
> 4561d01e-f9c1-4b5a-ab09-9bbb8270c9e0::nsdysz7n3ujdha2hyjekizfv8:
> "/node_modules/@prisma/client/mastip": not found

It's strange because if I uncomment the third line, it works, and if i comment out the first line it works.

If I replace the inserter and the mastip folders with new empty folders it works. Could it be that the two folders have some duplicate files or some symlinks or something that causes this to fail?

also

```
rk@Roberts-Air ~ % docker -v 
Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b
```

for what it's worth both directories look like this:

```
rk@Roberts-Air thred % ls -l node_modules/@prisma/client/mastip 
total 160056
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff        23 Dec 30 07:46 edge.d.ts
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff     13311 Dec 30 07:46 edge.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff      5578 Dec 30 07:46 index-browser.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff    166159 Dec 30 07:46 index.d.ts
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff     14994 Dec 30 07:46 index.js
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 rk  staff  15498696 Dec 30 07:46 libquery_engine-darwin-arm64.dylib.node
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 rk  staff  17621176 Dec 30 07:46 libquery_engine-linux-arm64-openssl-3.0.x.so.node
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 rk  staff  17981600 Dec 30 07:46 libquery_engine-linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x.so.node
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 rk  staff  15308896 Dec 30 07:46 libquery_engine-linux-musl-openssl-3.0.x.so.node
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 rk  staff  15304864 Dec 30 07:46 libquery_engine-linux-musl.so.node
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff       134 Dec 30 07:46 package.json
drwxr-xr-x@ 8 rk  staff       256 Dec 29 20:38 runtime
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff      2379 Dec 30 07:46 schema.prisma
rk@Roberts-Air thred % ls -l node_modules/@prisma/client/mastip/runtime 
total 1568
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff  214041 Dec 30 07:46 edge-esm.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff  214194 Dec 30 07:46 edge.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff   12314 Dec 30 07:46 index-browser.d.ts
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff   34302 Dec 30 07:46 index-browser.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff   95767 Dec 30 07:46 library.d.ts
-rw-r--r--@ 1 rk  staff  182956 Dec 30 07:46 library.js
```

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?  Directly copying the `node_modules` tree from the host seems a little unusual (there are some potential problems if the host and container aren't the same OS); can you `RUN npm ci` in your Dockerfile to rebuild the `node_modules` tree from the `package-lock.lson` listing?

Comment: no .dockerignore file.
long story, but usually i do a npm ci, however in this case, prisma doesn't know which clients to generate during the install. I generate clients ahead of time if dependent apps are affected. (but I generate them for the required architecture so hopefully host and container can be different OS).
I could install prisma & do another generate step in the container, although it slows things down a bit for many apps, and the dockerfile would then need to know what database clients the app  is using. Actually I guess i might end up taking that approach, thanks for suggestion

Comment: @DavidMaze just thinking, if i add a build step to my dockerfile to generate the clients, it won't increase the image size for cold starts, because i can copy only whats needed from the build step to the release step of the final image. However, that final copy, would i then get the same error as i'm already experiencing? IMO, the problem i'm experiencing is a bug with docker, maybe i should just try downgrade.